# How to delete data from csv file using python

Tags: python, csv

I am scraping a website for the course number and the course name. But if a course number does not have a name or vice versa, the data should be skipped from the final output. I do not know how to do that.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import urlopen 
import csv

source = urlopen('https://www.rit.edu/study/computing-security-bs')

csv_file1 = open('scrape.csv', 'w')
csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file1)
csv_writer.writerow(['Course Number', 'Course Name'])

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

table = soup.find('div', class_='processed-table')
#print(table)

curriculum = table.find('curriculum')
#print(curriculum.prettify())

next = curriculum.find('table', class_='table-curriculum')
#print(next.prettify())

for course_num in next.find_all('tr', class_='hidden-row rows-1'):
    num = course_num.find_all('td')[0]
    real = num.get_text()
#   print(real)
    realstr = real.encode('utf-8')

    name = course_num.find('div', class_='course-name')
    realname = name.get_text()
#   print(realname)
    realnamestr = realname.encode('utf-8')

    csv_writer.writerow([realstr, realnamestr])

csv_file1.close()
```

This is my csv
[csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSmPx.png)
I want to get rid of the last 4 rows.

Comment: Are you familiar with [`continue`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)?

Comment: not really, sorry

Comment: Well, then it's high time you went through the tutorial. You have to learn the basics before you start programming.

Answer (score 0):

As @zvone suggested, a continue will do the job here. Writing this answer as you mentioned you are not aware of the keyword.

Before, `csv_writer.writerow([realstr, realnamestr])` just put an `if` to check the `realstr` and `continue`:

```
if realstr.stip() == "":
    continue
```

I think you should still go through the `continue`, `break` and `else` keywords and how they can be helpful in controlling your loops.

Another approach would be to put data into `csv_writer` only when `realstr` has some value. So:

```
if realstr.strip != "":
    csv_writer.writerow([realstr, realnamestr])
```